# [Python][Pandas] Efficiently crossing and comparing the values in columns of two groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am currently trying to cross the data of two dataframes (df and marche_type_jointure) about bus journeys grouped by certain columns (in english: *stop, direction, type of day, season, year*) as the code here shows:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['arret', 'sens', 'type_jour','saison', 'annee'])
marche_type_jointure_grouped = marche_type_jointure.groupby(['arret', 'sens', 'type_jour','saison', 'annee'])
```

Which gives me the following dataframes with the following relevant columns (see screenshots [df_variables_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaxkT.png), [df_variables_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgISZ.png), [marche_type_variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHnYA.png)) and you can use the following dataframes as examples (only the most important variables as you can see):

```
df_jointure = pd.DataFrame([
['Aller','VIG01A' , time(7,21,28),'vac_s' ,'hiver' ,1978 , 'NaN' ], 
['Aller','VIG01A' , time(18,7,35),'vac_s' ,'hiver' ,1978 , 'NaN' ], 
['Aller','LYC30R' , time(7,21,54),'vac_s' ,'hiver' ,1978 , 'NaN' ], 
['Aller','LYC30R' , time(14,43,42),'vac_s' ,'hiver' ,1978 , 'NaN' ] ], columns=['sens', 'arret', 'heure_arrivee_reelle', 'type_jour', 'saison', 'annee', 'temps_trajet_mt'])


marche_type_jointure = df = pd.DataFrame([
['VIG01A', time(6,0,0), time(6,29,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 4, 'vac_s', 1978],
['VIG01A', time(7,0,0), time(7,29,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 4, 'vac_s', 1978], 
['VIG01A', time(7,0,0), time(7,59,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 4, 'vac_s', 1978], 
['VIG01A', time(18,30,0), time(18,59,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 4, 'vac_s', 1978], 
['LYC30R', time(6,0,0), time(6,29,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 1, 'semaine', 1978], 
['LYC30R', time(7,45,0), time(7,59,0), 'hiver', 'Aller', 1, 'semaine', 1978],
['LYC30R', time(9,30,0), time(15,59,00), 'hiver', 'Aller', 1, 'semaine', 1978]], 
columns=['arret', 'heure_debut_periode', 'heure_fin_periode', 'saison', 'sens', 'temps_trajet_sur_periode', 'type_jour', 'annee])
```

Here are also the most important variables:
in df : `'sens'` (column 6),
`'arret'` (*stop*, column 9),
`'heure_arrivee_reelle'` (actual time of arrival (of the bus), column 13),
`'type_jour'` (*type of day*, with 'vac_s' which means *holidays*, 'samedi' which is *saturday*, 'dimanche' which is *sunday*, and eventually 'semaine' which means *week*, column 25),
`'saison'` (which is season: 'hiver' for winter or 'ete' for summer, column 26),
`'annee'` (which is year, either 2018 or 1978 that refers winter 2017-2018, i.e. from January 2017 to May 2017 then September 2017 to May 2018, column 29),
'**temps_trajet_mt**' which is empty for the moment but the values will come from 'marche_type_jointure_grouped'(.temps_trajet_sur_periode).

For marche_type_jointure_grouped: `'arret'`  (stop), `'heure_debut_periode'` and `'heure_fin_periode'` which are the beginning and ending of a certain period of time in which there is a certain `'temps_trajet_sur_periode'` which is the time necessary to go from the previous stop to the one we're at (in the bus line). `'type_jour'`, `'saison'` and `'sens'` are the same as in `df_grouped`.

What I'm actually looking to do is, for each 'key' of the grouped dataframes(stop, direction, type of day, season and year), compare the value `'heure_arrivee_reelle'` ('*actual_time_of_arrival*' in english) in `df_grouped` with the different values of `'heure_fin_periode'` ('*end_time_period*' in english) and/or `'heure_debut_periode'`('*starting_time_period*' following this condition :
'if heure_arrivee_reelle in [heure_debut_periode, heure_fin_periode]' (as an **interval**, but there might be an easier condition giving the same result) `then the value of temps_trajet_mt in df_grouped becomes the corresponding value of temps_trajet_sur_periode in marche_type_jointure_grouped`.
Obviously I'm looking to do it in an efficient way. Here's what I tried to do so that maybe you understand a little bit more what I'm trying to do:

```
for key,group in df_grouped:
df_mt = marche_type_jointure_grouped.get_group(key) #we take the corresponding group from the other dataframe
index_har = list(group.heure_arrivee_reelle.index.values) #list of index of actual arrival times from df_grouped referring to key
index_hdp = list(df_mt.heure_debut_periode.index.values) #list of index of beginning time of period from marche_type_jointure_grouped refering to key
for i in index_hdp:
    for j in index_har:
        if df_mt.heure_fin_periode[i] >= group.heure_arrivee_reelle[j]:
            group.temps_trajet_mt[j] = df_mt.temps_trajet_sur_periode[i]
            index_har.remove(j) #so that I do not have to compare it again
        else:
            pass
df_grouped.size().unstack() #so that I can see the result
```

Thank you in advance for your help, it really means a lot I've been on this for more than a week now ! And please tell me if what I'm trying to do isn't clear (it's more or less a conditional joint, if you will...)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. For Pandas-specific advice, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I actually solved the problem: I used a merge and then two filters on my data after computing the time periods (instead of doing the comparison, I think it is more efficient). Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Sure, in that case you can post your own answer. This can help the wider community.